# Create a report with microsoft visual c# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, report

I'm using visual studio c# express, I want to creat a simple report but the problem is that vs is missing all the features for creating report I found this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbfdef7c-9dfe-479a-9806-c2c07b53879e/report-designer-in-visual-c-2010-express?forum=Vsexpressvcs

I've installed ReportViewer and I created my report using SQL Server Report Builder and changed .rdl to .rdlc and copied the report in to my win app but I don't know how to set the ReportDataSource

I've created a dataset in my win app and this is my code:

```
reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ("rptStockCount.rdlc"); 
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1")); 
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

and this is the error: cannot create a data reader from data set 1

Any suggestion or help?

Comment: The first reply explains *very clearly* that it doesn't come with the Express Edition, and you have to install it separately. What is your question?

Comment: I've installed ReportViewer but still it's not working, so I created my report using SQL Server Report Builder and changed .rdl to .rdlc and copied the report in to my win app but I don't know how to set the ReportDataSource

Comment: Don't add code as a comment. It's unreadable. Edit the original question to include that relevant code, and full error messages. While you're at it, remove all of the information about the express version, and not having report wizard, unless you really feel that it is relevant.